# difference between Private slots and private method in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT and I want to know the difference between

1) private slot vs private class methods

When we need to use private slot and when we need to use private methods

Comment: Very generic questions. Search the internet please: http://www.bing.com/search?q=difference+between+Private+slots+and+private+method+in+QT&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=difference+between+private+slots+and+private+method+in+qt&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=6F803423CEA7471D9BAC7C7F933BB8AF

Comment: Slots can be connected to signals through old-style connect syntax and can be enumerated/invoked through the QMetaObject associated to the class. That's about it.

Answer (score 5):

Please read [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/signalsandslots.html):
In a nutshell "Since slots are normal member functions, they follow the normal C++ rules when called directly. However, as slots, they can be invoked by any component, regardless of its access level, via a signal-slot connection. This means that a signal emitted from an instance of an arbitrary class can cause a private slot to be invoked in an instance of an unrelated class.
What this means: From another class, you can't call a private slot as a function, but if you emit a signal connected to that private slot, you can invoke it."